# how to query objects inside an object of a document from mongodb to retrieve matching key values based on the object's key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a below Document in a Mongo Collection.

```
{
   "_id":"1001",
   "country":{
      "country_name":"India",
      "capital_city":"Delhi",
      "national_animal":"tiger",
      "national_bird":"peacock",
      
      "states":{
         "data":[
            {
               state_name : "karnataka",
               state_capital : "Bangalore"
            },
            {
               state_name : "maharashtra",
               state_capital : "Mumbai"
            },
            {
               state_name : "tamilnadu",
               state_capital : "Chennai"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "country_name":"India",
   "root_table":"country"
}
```

From this JSON, I just wanted an object's key value pair based on the matching filter `{"state_name" : "maharashtra"}`.

The required result should be like this.

```
"states" : {
  state_name : "maharashtra",
  state_capital : "Mumbai"
}
```

OR

```
{
  state_name : "maharashtra",
  state_capital : "Mumbai"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this type of query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try aggregation query,

- `$match` to check `state_name` condition
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `data` array and check if `state_name` found
- `$arrayElemAt` to select first element from filtered result from above step
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "country.states.data.state_name": "maharashtra" } },
  {
    $project: {
      state: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$country.states.data",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.state_name", "maharashtra"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f2s2any7GEv)

---

You can use aggregation `$project` stage operators in `find()` method starting from MongoDB 4.4,

```
db.collection.find({
  "country.states.data.state_name": "maharashtra"
},
{
  state: {
    $arrayElemAt: [
      {
        $filter: {
          input: "$country.states.data",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.state_name", "maharashtra"] }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZYz1d1tzrUD)